# Topological spaces without higher homotopy and homology groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is there anything good in the class of objects with trivial higher homotopy and homology groups? Can it be described in some terms?

For example:
 such $X$ that $\pi_{\gg 0}(X) = 0$ and $H_{\gg 0}(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$

Comment: What do you mean by "anything good"? There are some useful examples, such as $S^1$ and any closed connected surface that isn't $S^2$ or $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: And there are wild things like Cantor sets, too. Also, what kind of answer are you expecting? Please be a bit more precise.

Comment: What does $\pi_{\gg 0}$ denote? Does it refer to $\pi_n$ for $n \geq 1$, $n \geq 2$, or $n \geq k$ for some choice of $k$?

Comment: Under these conditions, the Postnikov tower will be finite. So the homology groups will be determined by the homotopy groups together with certain cocycles in the homology of the terms of the tower with coefficients in the homotopy groups. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Postnikov+system#DefinitionForTopologicalSpaces  It seems likely to be quite intricate to determine in general when the homology will be finite.

Answer (score 13):

One thing you should bear in mind is the Kan-Thurston theorem: if $X$ is connected then there is a group $G$ and a map $f\colon BG\to X$ such that the induced map $H_*(BG)\to H_*(X)$ is an isomorphism.  Thus, if $H_i(X)=0$ for $i\gg 0$ then the space $BG$ will have $H_i(BG)=0$ for $i\gg 0$ and also $\pi_i(BG)=0$ for $i>1$.  Of course, the groups $G$ that arise in this context are typically quite strange and unfamiliar.

Comment: Sorry but, what is $BG$ ?

Comment: $BG$ is the classifying space of the group $G$. It is a space characterized up to homotopy by having the homotopy type of a CW-complex, being connected, having $\pi_1(BG,x) \cong G$ for any choice of basepoint, and all higher homotopy groups trivial.

Comment: Ian Leary gave an improved version where $BG$ is a non-positively curved polyhedral complex. (Maybe even a cube complex?) So the groups $G$ that arise needn't be *that* "strange and unfamiliar" -- they have solvable word problem, for instance.